# Browser not supported by Google Maps

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-11

i wrote a small progam (C#, WPF, .Net 4.6) with a Frame. After loading a HTML file with a google map I got this error:

> The browser you are using is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API. Use a different browser.

I already have add the follwing HTML-Code:

```
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

But it dosn't work any more.

Some one an idea why or what I should change?

Comment: What is your HTML presentation control? I guess edge is still pretty crippled so you probably better switch to a decent browser engine.

Comment: If  you load http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/ in that window, what does it show?

Comment: I use a '<Frame>' 
@mjwills it Show IE11, and this is supportet by Googles Maps API

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Seems to have started since installing this months update tuesday patches.

Comment: @mjwills it says "IE 11" I also try to install the newest version of java but the error is the same

Comment: @David I agree with you, the error occurs this mornig. Yesterday everthinks was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove this error by adding:

```
<style>
    .infomsg {display:none;}
</style>
```

Comment: My pleasure Stephan.

Comment: This just hides the message and does nothing to address the problem that Google Maps just won't work with IE 8 or below.  You'll get an empty white frame and a bunch of errors in the console.  Try it with a modern version of IE, F12, set the compatibility level to 8 or below.

Answer (score 0):

This post got it working for me: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version

It gives a few registry options (I used the entry in the HKLM part of the registry). The downside is that it seems to require a registry entry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change registry

SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
to true

check this

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version